# too much recursion error in tree

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello stackoverflow community. I need help with "too much recursion" error. It comes when I do these functions, weird, but everything works fine just error.:

```
function check_checker (siblings, status) {
    if (siblings) {
        if (status == true) {
            $(siblings).children('li.imCheckbox').children('input').prop( "checked", true );
            if ($(siblings).children('ul')) {
                check_checker($(siblings).children('ul'), true);
            }                                           
        } else {
            $(siblings).children('li.imCheckbox').children('input').prop( "checked", false );
            if ($(siblings).children('ul')) {
                check_checker($(siblings).children('ul'), false);
            }                                           
        }
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', 'input[name=impTaskCh]', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var siblingas = $(this).parent().siblings('ul');
            check_checker(siblingas, true);
        } else {
            var siblingas = $(this).parent().siblings('ul');
            check_checker(siblingas, false);
        }
    });
});
```

When check is clicked, if ul has ul it checks all the checkbox'es. Maby check_checker never ends or something? What you guys think?

Comment: `if ($(siblings).children('ul')) {` will always be `true` as jQuery selectors always return an object which coerces to true. Use `if ($(siblings).children('ul').length) {` instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan IT WORKED!! Write to answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is never ending. `$(siblings).children('ul')` will return an Object, which is truthy, so it will always be true. I would recommend using the length property instead.

```
function check_checker (siblings, status) {
    if (siblings) {
        if (status == true) {
            $(siblings).children('li.imCheckbox').children('input').prop( "checked", true );
            if ($(siblings).children('ul').length > 0) {
                check_checker($(siblings).children('ul'), true);
            }                                           
        } else {
            $(siblings).children('li.imCheckbox').children('input').prop( "checked", false );
            if ($(siblings).children('ul').length > 0) {
                check_checker($(siblings).children('ul'), false);
            }                                           
        }
    }
}
```